# Apache Ant: Running a job without displaying a specified target name

Tags: jenkins, ant

I am working with ant and calling a build.xml from jenkins.
I have 3 targets (t1, t2, t3).
When I start a job in the log I got something likes this:

```
t1:
 my first target

t2:
 my second target

t3:
 my third target
```

I am trying to leave one specified target name from the log, and one specified target text.

I'd like the log not to show a specific target name and content. But only for a specified target. The rest of the existing targets should appear.
I'd like to have something like this (whithout 2 target name and contents, for example):

```
 t1:
   my first target

 t3:
 my third target
```

Now, I've tried to call targets in the jenkins like this:

```
targets: -q t1
```

But with -q it remove all targets name and contents.
How can I accomplish to remove only a specified target name and content?

Answer (score 0):

After spending some hours investigating I found out that I could put this code in a target.

```
<script language="javascript">
    var logger = project.getBuildListeners( ).firstElement( );
    logger.setMessageOutputLevel( 0 );
</script>
```

After this no log will appear. 
When I want to activate logs again I could just do this:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var logger = project.getBuildListeners( ).firstElement( );
    logger.setMessageOutputLevel( 0 );
</script>
```

After this everything will show up again...